# PySerial Works in a different way with USB to rs232 and MAX3232CDR

Tags: python, pyserial

Can anyone explain where my mistake is

```
import time, serial
from _poll_msg import *
from exception import BadCRC
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.baudrate= 19200
ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB0'
ser.open()

def write(cmd):
    ser.flushOutput()
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_MARK
    ser.write(('82'+ mashin_n).decode('hex'))
    crc = crc_sas(mashin_n + cmd)
    cmd = cmd + crc
    ser.parity = serial.PARITY_SPACE
    ser.write(cmd.decode('hex'))
    return True

def read(size):
    response = ser.read(size).encode('hex')
    # with ttyUSB? response is 011912345678crc
    # with ttyS? response = 0101010101
    # but error is in write (010101 - command is bad)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    try:
        crc_sas(response, chk=True)
    except BadCRC:
        return False
    return response[4:-4]
```

It works without error.
But if I change port to /dev/ttyS1
It does not work.
Where's the difference and where I'm wrong.

Comment: Exception is BadCRC. From doc response is: mashin_n, cmd, 4 bit bcd, 2 bit crc (011912345678crc)
If port is /dev/ttyS? It return 010101010101 (comand is bad)

Comment: No python traceback just machin not recognize command.

Comment: Oh, you are messing about with parity in the write function. Oh, go figure.

Comment: Communication is 9 bit
Parity makes that. With USB it work. Function write and read 24 h 7 day on every 0.5 s and their 3 bad crc exception